# Youtube shows api not listing shows for user

Tags: youtube-api

This api is not working for zeetv, sabtv, colorstv, and more users.
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/shows?v=2

It was working before but now it is not working. Is it removed by youtube?
When I open this url it shows me total 0 shows. But when I check with youtube shows, it list all shows for particular user. Why is so happening ?
Please reply back.